# How to implement the new Material Design Bottom App Bar

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, material-design, vue-material

My company currently uses Vue and scss to build our latest PWA. Given certain conditions (based on the user profile), the left drawer should be replaced by a Bottom App Bar.

We are using [Vue Material](https://vuematerial.io/) but our UX and UI designer chose to use the latest version of the [Bottom App Bar](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#usage) released by Google.

However, the CSS for this particular component haven't been released yet and isn't part of the VueMaterial components library ([which currently support the older version](https://vuematerial.io/components/bottom-bar)) and I'm struggling to reproduce the second version of the new bar.

[I can't post images so here is the link of what I'm refering to](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1xkb-3HQEAsb0IA292GLCziMMh6QE1YIX%2Fanatomy-fab-cut.png)

I do not understand how it is possible, using a CSS only solution, to reproduce the inset between the bar and the FAB. I tried to solve the problem using clip-path and mask-image without much success.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of different options. I've added background images so it is clear that the cutout is transparent.

**Box-shadow on a pseudo element**

Doesn't give the rounded corners and isn't very flexible.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 56px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -32px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5000px rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

**Loads of clip path points**

Code taken from [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/MarcinKokoszka/pen/XPmpwo).

Not the easiest to configure but could probably create a preprocessor mixin to handle the generation of those points. Definitely gives a much better effect than the box-shadow technique.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 56px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 
    calc(50% - 38px) 0, 
    calc(50% - 37.487665px) 0.628287px, 
    calc(50% - 36.975331px) 1.256382px, 
    calc(50% - 36.462997px) 1.884094px, 
    calc(50% - 35.912306px) 2.511233px, 
    calc(50% - 35.863009px) 3.137607px, 
    calc(50% - 35.802788px) 3.763025px, 
    calc(50% - 35.731661px) 4.387296px, 
    calc(50% - 35.64965px) 5.010232px, 
    calc(50% - 35.55678px) 5.631641px, 
    calc(50% - 35.453079px) 6.251334px, 
    calc(50% - 35.338579px) 6.869124px, 
    calc(50% - 35.213314px) 7.484821px, 
    calc(50% - 35.077322px) 8.098238px, 
    calc(50% - 34.930646px) 8.709188px, 
    calc(50% - 34.77333px) 9.317486px, 
    calc(50% - 34.605421px) 9.922945px, 
    calc(50% - 34.426971px) 10.525381px, 
    calc(50% - 34.238035px) 11.124612px, 
    calc(50% - 34.038669px) 11.720454px, 
    calc(50% - 33.828934px) 12.312725px, 
    calc(50% - 33.608895px) 12.901246px, 
    calc(50% - 33.378619px) 13.485837px, 
    calc(50% - 33.138175px) 14.066321px, 
    calc(50% - 32.887636px) 14.642519px, 
    calc(50% - 32.62708px) 15.214257px, 
    calc(50% - 32.356586px) 15.781361px, 
    calc(50% - 32.076235px) 16.343658px, 
    calc(50% - 31.786113px) 16.900976px, 
    calc(50% - 31.486309px) 17.453146px, 
    calc(50% - 31.176915px) 18px, 
    calc(50% - 30.858023px) 18.541371px, 
    calc(50% - 30.529731px) 19.077094px, 
    calc(50% - 30.19214px) 19.607005px, 
    calc(50% - 29.845353px) 20.130945px, 
    calc(50% - 29.489474px) 20.648752px, 
    calc(50% - 29.124612px) 21.160269px, 
    calc(50% - 28.750878px) 21.665341px, 
    calc(50% - 28.368387px) 22.163813px, 
    calc(50% - 27.977255px) 22.655534px, 
    calc(50% - 27.5776px) 23.140354px, 
    calc(50% - 27.169545px) 23.618125px, 
    calc(50% - 26.753214px) 24.088702px, 
    calc(50% - 26.328733px) 24.551941px, 
    calc(50% - 25.896233px) 25.007701px, 
    calc(50% - 25.455844px) 25.455844px, 
    calc(50% - 25.007701px) 25.896233px, 
    calc(50% - 24.551941px) 26.328733px, 
    calc(50% - 24.088702px) 26.753214px, 
    calc(50% - 23.618125px) 27.169545px, 
    calc(50% - 23.140354px) 27.5776px, 
    calc(50% - 22.655534px) 27.977255px, 
    calc(50% - 22.163813px) 28.368387px, 
    calc(50% - 21.665341px) 28.750878px, 
    calc(50% - 21.160269px) 29.124612px, 
    calc(50% - 20.648752px) 29.489474px, 
    calc(50% - 20.130945px) 29.845353px, 
    calc(50% - 19.607005px) 30.19214px, 
    calc(50% - 19.077094px) 30.529731px, 
    calc(50% - 18.541371px) 30.858023px, 
    calc(50% - 18px) 31.176915px, 
    calc(50% - 17.453146px) 31.486309px, 
    calc(50% - 16.900976px) 31.786113px, 
    calc(50% - 16.343658px) 32.076235px, 
    calc(50% - 15.781361px) 32.356586px, 
    calc(50% - 15.214257px) 32.62708px, 
    calc(50% - 14.642519px) 32.887636px, 
    calc(50% - 14.066321px) 33.138175px, 
    calc(50% - 13.485837px) 33.378619px, 
    calc(50% - 12.901246px) 33.608895px, 
    calc(50% - 12.312725px) 33.828934px, 
    calc(50% - 11.720454px) 34.038669px, 
    calc(50% - 11.124612px) 34.238035px, 
    calc(50% - 10.525381px) 34.426971px, 
    calc(50% - 9.922945px) 34.605421px, 
    calc(50% - 9.317486px) 34.77333px, 
    calc(50% - 8.709188px) 34.930646px, 
    calc(50% - 8.098238px) 35.077322px, 
    calc(50% - 7.484821px) 35.213314px, 
    calc(50% - 6.869124px) 35.338579px, 
    calc(50% - 6.251334px) 35.453079px, 
    calc(50% - 5.631641px) 35.55678px, 
    calc(50% - 5.010232px) 35.64965px, 
    calc(50% - 4.387296px) 35.731661px, 
    calc(50% - 3.763025px) 35.802788px, 
    calc(50% - 3.137607px) 35.863009px, 
    calc(50% - 2.511233px) 35.912306px, 
    calc(50% - 1.884094px) 35.950663px, 
    calc(50% - 1.256382px) 35.97807px, 
    calc(50% - 0.628287px) 35.994517px, 
    50% 36px, 
    calc(50% + 0.628287px) 35.994517px, 
    calc(50% + 1.256382px) 35.97807px, 
    calc(50% + 1.884094px) 35.950663px, 
    calc(50% + 2.511233px) 35.912306px, 
    calc(50% + 3.137607px) 35.863009px, 
    calc(50% + 3.763025px) 35.802788px, 
    calc(50% + 4.387296px) 35.731661px, 
    calc(50% + 5.010232px) 35.64965px, 
    calc(50% + 5.631641px) 35.55678px, 
    calc(50% + 6.251334px) 35.453079px, 
    calc(50% + 6.869124px) 35.338579px, 
    calc(50% + 7.484821px) 35.213314px, 
    calc(50% + 8.098238px) 35.077322px, 
    calc(50% + 8.709188px) 34.930646px, 
    calc(50% + 9.317486px) 34.77333px, 
    calc(50% + 9.922945px) 34.605421px, 
    calc(50% + 10.525381px) 34.426971px, 
    calc(50% + 11.124612px) 34.238035px, 
    calc(50% + 11.720454px) 34.038669px, 
    calc(50% + 12.312725px) 33.828934px, 
    calc(50% + 12.901246px) 33.608895px, 
    calc(50% + 13.485837px) 33.378619px, 
    calc(50% + 14.066321px) 33.138175px, 
    calc(50% + 14.642519px) 32.887636px, 
    calc(50% + 15.214257px) 32.62708px, 
    calc(50% + 15.781361px) 32.356586px, 
    calc(50% + 16.343658px) 32.076235px, 
    calc(50% + 16.900976px) 31.786113px, 
    calc(50% + 17.453146px) 31.486309px, 
    calc(50% + 18px) 31.176915px, 
    calc(50% + 18.541371px) 30.858023px, 
    calc(50% + 19.077094px) 30.529731px, 
    calc(50% + 19.607005px) 30.19214px, 
    calc(50% + 20.130945px) 29.845353px, 
    calc(50% + 20.648752px) 29.489474px, 
    calc(50% + 21.160269px) 29.124612px, 
    calc(50% + 21.665341px) 28.750878px, 
    calc(50% + 22.163813px) 28.368387px, 
    calc(50% + 22.655534px) 27.977255px, 
    calc(50% + 23.140354px) 27.5776px, 
    calc(50% + 23.618125px) 27.169545px, 
    calc(50% + 24.088702px) 26.753214px, 
    calc(50% + 24.551941px) 26.328733px, 
    calc(50% + 25.007701px) 25.896233px, 
    calc(50% + 25.455844px) 25.455844px, 
    calc(50% + 25.896233px) 25.007701px, 
    calc(50% + 26.328733px) 24.551941px, 
    calc(50% + 26.753214px) 24.088702px, 
    calc(50% + 27.169545px) 23.618125px, 
    calc(50% + 27.5776px) 23.140354px, 
    calc(50% + 27.977255px) 22.655534px, 
    calc(50% + 28.368387px) 22.163813px, 
    calc(50% + 28.750878px) 21.665341px, 
    calc(50% + 29.124612px) 21.160269px, 
    calc(50% + 29.489474px) 20.648752px, 
    calc(50% + 29.845353px) 20.130945px, 
    calc(50% + 30.19214px) 19.607005px, 
    calc(50% + 30.529731px) 19.077094px, 
    calc(50% + 30.858023px) 18.541371px, 
    calc(50% + 31.176915px) 18px, 
    calc(50% + 31.486309px) 17.453146px, 
    calc(50% + 31.786113px) 16.900976px, 
    calc(50% + 32.076235px) 16.343658px, 
    calc(50% + 32.356586px) 15.781361px, 
    calc(50% + 32.62708px) 15.214257px, 
    calc(50% + 32.887636px) 14.642519px, 
    calc(50% + 33.138175px) 14.066321px, 
    calc(50% + 33.378619px) 13.485837px, 
    calc(50% + 33.608895px) 12.901246px, 
    calc(50% + 33.828934px) 12.312725px, 
    calc(50% + 34.038669px) 11.720454px, 
    calc(50% + 34.238035px) 11.124612px, 
    calc(50% + 34.426971px) 10.525381px, 
    calc(50% + 34.605421px) 9.922945px, 
    calc(50% + 34.77333px) 9.317486px, 
    calc(50% + 34.930646px) 8.709188px, 
    calc(50% + 35.077322px) 8.098238px, 
    calc(50% + 35.213314px) 7.484821px, 
    calc(50% + 35.338579px) 6.869124px, 
    calc(50% + 35.453079px) 6.251334px, 
    calc(50% + 35.55678px) 5.631641px, 
    calc(50% + 35.64965px) 5.010232px, 
    calc(50% + 35.731661px) 4.387296px, 
    calc(50% + 35.802788px) 3.763025px, 
    calc(50% + 35.863009px) 3.137607px, 
    calc(50% + 35.912306px) 2.511233px, 
    calc(50% + 36.462997px) 1.884094px, 
    calc(50% + 36.975331px) 1.256382px, 
    calc(50% + 37.487665px) 0.628287px, 
    calc(50% + 38px) 0, 
    100% 0, 
    100% 100%, 
    0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

**SVG clip path**

I can't think of a way to get this to work without having to modify the path with javascript. It does however let you create any shape you like.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 56px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: url(#circle);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circle">
      <path d="M0,64 v-64 h100 a32,32 0,0,0 64,0 h100 v64 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction there ! I finally used your first solution for the moment as the material specs are unclear about the rounded edges.

Comment: James, thanks for these pointers! I used clip-path method and put the FAB button off on the right with other icon action on the bottom app bar, see https://biblescout.app/#!/law-and-prophets .

Answer (score 0):

Many possebilities, but here is a simple exmaple:

```
$size: 45px;

div {
  background: #550000;
  float:left;
}

.bottom {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px * 2;
}
.left, .right{
  height: 45px * 1.5;
  width: 45px * 2;
}  
.bottom {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 45px * 2;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 45px * 2;
}
.top {
  height: 45px*1.28;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.left {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.right {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="top"><div class="bottom"></div></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YMZwBM

Comment: if that is a requirement then using and svg/polygon or image for background is probably the way to go.